# Chef: how do I restart a service after creating two files?

Tags: file, service, resources, notifications, chef-infra

I want to install known ssh host keys then restart the openssh service.  For one file it is simple enough:

```
file 'new_file' do
  owner 'owner'
  mode 00600
  content 'my content'
  notifies :restart, 'service[openssh]', :immediately
end
```

But I want to do this after having moved two files.

I can:

1. Sequentially create the files; restarting openssh in the context of the second one.
2. Wrap both file moves in a **ruby_block** resource that has it's own Notification to openssh.

I'm not 100% sure #2 will work the way I want, and #1 doesn't "feel" correct either.  Am I guaranteed that the first file creation would occur before the second one?

So my question is: **With Chef, what's the best way to restart ssh after creating two new files?**

Answer (score 2):

If you have a restart for both files and don't use `:immediately`, Chef will queue up the two restarts and perform a single restart at the last stage of the client run.  Unless you have something else in mind, it probably isn't necessary to use `:immediately` when restarting the ssh daemon.

Also, Chef guarantees that resources will be processed in the order in which they appear in your recipe so the first file will always be created before the second.

Comment: Or if you need to restart `openssh` immediately, do it in the second `file` resource declaration. As Tim said, they will be processed in order.